# Breeze Query Execution Error For An Entity With NotMapped Property

Tags: breeze

I have a **collection** property in my model class with [NotMapped] attribute. I am using breeze query (method in breeze controller) to get the records of same entity. I have initialized the not mapped property in custom entity constructor and also registered that constructor.
But the breeze query always gives an exception saying "undefined" is not a function. The error is always there even if I skip initializing the not mapped property in constructor.

Comment: This was happening because the model class contained a collection property of its own type. Added a new model class and exposed its collection as a property from the original model class.

Comment: Thanks for the update and I'm glad you figured it out. For future reference, a more detailed explanation and relevant code to reproduce the problem will make it easier for us to understand the problem and expedite a response.